# При просмотре кода появился длинный прямоугольник, это нормально и что делать?

Tags: html, css3

Вобщем делаю я меню и просмотрел код элемента появился вот этот длинный прямоугольник.Меню находиться в теге section.Тоже самая проблема у второго. Меню работает но я смотрел у других сайтов у них такого нет. Это нормально? Если нет помогите исправить, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем делаю я меню и просмотрел код элемента появился вот этот длинный прямоугольник.Меню находиться в теге section.Тоже самая проблема у второго. Меню работает но я смотрел у других сайтов у них такого нет. Это нормально? Если нет помогите исправить, пожалуйста!

[image: Вот то самое меню.]